# How does HTML 5 differ from HTML 4?

Tags: html, html4

I have seen HTML 5 coming up in near future. How does it differ from HTML 4, which has been 'in' for so many years in web development?

thanks

Comment: Not to be "that guy", but did you even try looking for an answer? Googling your very title yields the answer.

Comment: @Jonatan Hedborg: You are missing the point of Stack Overflow--no questions are too dumb. This is a database of questions for every programmer--not just the experts. And most times; dumb questions != dumb answers.

Comment: I disagree. It's always a good thing to at least try to find information by yourself first. Always.
If for no other reason than to learn HOW to find information by yourself... I dont think the idea of stackOverflow is to make people lazy.

Comment: You don't need to learn how to find information anymore, you can just type it in to google or ask someone. I'm sure though almost all the questions on SO could be found be searching the internet, yet they are still asked here. Maybe he just wants to be able to have the option to ask something about the answer if he doesn't understand something.

Comment: @Jonathan: so let him google and ask about what he doesn't understand.

Comment: its quicker just to ask it in one go surely, and isn't the entire point of technology, the internet etc to make things easier?

Comment: One hand no question is too basic but I think this question is too general. He could use doing a bit of research for such a question. Taken to the extreme it's a bit like asking 'how do you program?'. It's not a dumb question but it does not quite fit the SO model.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Broadly speaking, there are four main areas of change:

- Semantic markup, including the following tags:

  `<section>`
  `<article>`
  `<header>`
  `<footer>`
  `<nav>`
  `<aside>`
  `<hgroup>`

  This also covers changes to the `<doctype>`, `<html>` and `<meta>` tags, as well as link relations (the rel attribute on an `<a>` tag).
- Improved form support - mainly semantic additions to input types, and a few neat things like field autofocus and placeholder text.
- Multimedia tags - `<video>`, `<audio>` and `<canvas>`. `<video>` and `<audio>` are intended to improved better support for embedded media in the page; `<canvas>` is for programmatic two-dimensional bitmap drawing on the page through JavaScript.
- Changes to the DOM that are just accessible through JS - `navigator.geolocation`, `window.localStorage` (storing user data offline), `window.applicationCache` (storing app data offline), web workers (multithreaded JavaScript, with some caveats)

Different parts of HTML are in different stages of specification and implementation - the form changes are poorly supported outside of Safari, the `<video>` tag is basically unusable in a cross-platform environment (without multiple video formats), and IE has built-in support for next to none of these changes.

The best place to read up on HTML5 that I've seen is Mark Pilgrim's excellent book in progress, [Dive into HTML5](http://diveintohtml5.info/)

Answer (score 11):

[Difference between HTML 5 and HTML 4](http://www.hobo-web.co.uk/seo-blog/index.php/html5-html4-different/)

[And as per W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5-diff/)

Answer (score 11):

Consider these images (from [www.alistapart.com](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/previewofhtml5)), the structure of a page is hugely different:

**HTML4**

[image: HTML4]

**HTML5**

[image: HTML5]

This is just an example, take a look on other comments for articles about this subject

Comment: So does this means that we can specify arbitrary tags?

Comment: @Alix Axel: No. There's just gonna be some new, more semantic HTML-elements to play around with.

Comment: No, it is not possible to specify arbitrary tags; these tags are just new tags:
http://www.w3schools.com/html5/html5_reference.asp

Comment: @Harmen Can the article and section mean *anything*? I mean, what's the original intent of the <article> and <section> elements?

Answer (score 5):

[HTML 5 differences from HTML 4](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5-diff/) by W3C

Answer (score 1):

If you are hesitant to read through a thousand pages of HTML5 specification, take a look at **[this article](http://www.techradar.com/news/internet/why-html5-is-here-today-and-not-2022-654828?artc_pg=1)**. It will give you a good overview of what HTML5 is all about, and it goes to explain how you can use HTML5 right now, since most A-grade browsers actually supports most of the new goodies; like the new HTML-elements and embedded video/audio.

Comment: You're exaggerating somewhat. The spec is only 660 pages.